# Can't see Windows Service Installed

Tags: c#, windows-services

I created a super simple Windows Service program. I selected program Project -> Windows Service, after that I changed the `this.ServiceName = "servicename1";` to `` `this.ServiceName = "ABC Test Service"; ``

After that I created a setup project, set primary output as the Windows Service. Compiled and installed it all.

But the Service is not visible under the Services UI, and I can't figure out why it is not visible. This solution is as straight out of the box as I can possible imagine. I haven't done anything major to the code as is. Yet I'm missing something so that I can see the installed service.

Have I added anything major, which is not part of the initial project - I've added something in the `OnStart(string[] args)` / `OnStop()`. Though I wouldn't call it major.

Have I changed something which is part of the initial project.
- I've renamed the partial class

```
public partial class ABCTestService : ServiceBase  
{  
    public ABCTestService()  
    {  
        InitializeComponent();  
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service Start");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service Stop");
    }
}
```

The service was also invisible before I changed the name of the partial class. Install goes through without a single word of warning or error of any kind. So service must be installed, so it should be visible.

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new ABCTestService() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

What now says `ABCTestService()`, did say `Service1()`. Before I changed the name of the partial class, and VS2010 changed the name all over.

Comment: Did you use the `InstallUtil.exe` tool from `C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/vX.x.xxxx` to install your service?

Comment: [Edit] and add your Main method of the service application.  If you have one.  If you don't, there's your problem.

Comment: I installed directly from VS2010.

Comment: Main is there alright. I just tried pasting it. But it won't show up nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

Install:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\installutil C:\MySampleService\bin\Debug\MyService.exe
```

Uninstall:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\installutil /u C:\MySampleService\bin\Debug\MyService.exe
```

There is also a shorter way to install the service with parameters that you can specify from the command line when starting the service. Both essentially perform the same task. Note that the first method will log progress and details, whereas I have left this out of the 'shortcut' solution.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            string parameter = string.Concat(args);

            switch (parameter)
            {
                case "--install":

                    ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });

                    break;
                case "--uninstall":

                    ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });

                    break;
            }
        }
```

and my OnStart method simply executes the code I wish

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //MyCode
    }
```

Also, I have found it beneficial to write my service as a console application for the ease of development and debugging. When you complete this, simply turn it into a service by creating your installer and running it in the ways listed above. Also notice the if (Environment.UserInteractive) statement. The else to this will fire as if running a console app, giving you the earlier mentioned advantage of debugging/developing in a friendlier environment.

EDIT

*Include an installer if you have not e.g. ProjectInstaller.cs

Ensure your ProjectInstaller.cs is configured correctly. (Perhaps you are not assigning a proper name). Here is the stripped version of mine, using "MyService" as the name

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
        this.serviceInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
        // 
        // serviceProcessInstaller1
        // 

        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = "username";
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = @"password";
        // 
        // serviceInstaller1
        // 
        this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "MyService";
        // 
        // ProjectInstaller
        // 
        this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1,
        this.serviceInstaller1});

    }

    private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller1;
    private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller1;

}
```

Comment: I had a look at your suggestion. When I noticed you didn't run it on the setup project, but on the service project itself I was able to get a Installation Completed. Yet I still can't see the service under the Windows Services UI.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check out if you need to give it a name inside the code. Other than that, I can not see why you wouldn't see it in your local services.

Comment: I can't see any mention of adding a service installer to the service project at all in the OP, and was just about to post an answer along those lines, but your edit seems to have it covered.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: And second paragraph - "After that I created a setup project.." ?

Comment: @DoStuffZ - I assume by that you meant that you created a visual studio setup project (or a Wix project, or an InstallShield project). A Service Installer is a class that lives within the same assembly as the service class, and is typically added by clicking the "add service installer" at the bottom of the properties window when looking at the service's properties. I wouldn't describe it as a "setup **project**" - however, if that's what you meant, I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: You are right, we are talking about two different things then. I'm looking for your button to click.

Comment: @DoStuffZ - added an answer with the details.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a Service Installer to your service project. The easiest way to do this is to close all code windows. Then double click your service and it should open the service in Design View.

At the bottom of the properties window now should be a link called "Add Installer". Click that and it should add a Project Installer, which will include a Service Installer and a Service Process installer. These have properties such as the user account under which your service should run, etc.

It's this class that contains the logic to install your service.

Comment: I'll have a look at it, next time I get a spare moment. For now this research has been super seeded with a real task.

Comment: Thanks, I found where it was hidden, and added it.